# How can I determine what size Postgres RDS to scale to to allow quicker copy to csv?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, copy

I have a table in Postgres that I know will become a 5 GB csv. Right now I've got a t2.micro RDS, and the copy of that table to csv is slow. How can I figure out what size to scale up to (I'm guessing in read IOPS) so that the copy happens in say, half an hour?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are guessing. You need to look at CloudWatch metrics to determine exactly what the bottleneck is. It could be IOPS on your EBS volume, or it could be CPU usage, memory usage, or possibly you are running out of T2 instance CPU credits. You could also be running into network bandwidth limitations between your EC2 instance and your EBS volume.

Once you see which metric is being maxed out it will be obvious what you need to upgrade. If you need a faster CPU or more memory you can upgrade to a larger instance. If you are running into issues with CPU credits you might want to switch to a different instance type such as M4. If you are running into IOPS issues you could simply add an EBS volume with provisioned IOPS, or use a larger SSD volume that comes with a higher base IOPS. If it is an issue of network communication between your EBS volume and your EC2 instance, then you could upgrade to an EBS Optimized instance type.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information! I simplified a little -- it was actually someone else attempting the copying and I didn't know when they would try, so couldn't just monitor metrics. I guess I could have additionally done a copy locally to investigate, but do you have any intuition on which component tends to be the bottleneck?

Comment: I don't understand why you say you can't look at the metrics. They are stored in CloudWatch, go look at them. You don't have to be sitting there staring at them at the moment the issue happens. I'm not about to make a guess as to what could possibly be the issue, and I think my original answer details very well why I think guessing is a bad idea. Run a test yourself if you need to capture new metrics.

Comment: I find your comment very passive aggressive. If you don't know what the bottleneck usually is, just say so instead of complaining about me asking and telling me to "run a test myself". The point of stack is to get faster answers than running every test yourself and it's a completely legitimate question.

Comment: The fastest possible way to get your answer is to go look in CloudWatch at your historical data. That's all I'm trying to tell you. Take it however you will, but if you wanted the fastest possible answer you would have looked at CloudWatch instead of even asking the question here. I'm just trying to point you to the method of getting the actual correct answer, instead of guessing and making lots of changes that will cost money and time and may not solve your issue.